# How can I make certain areas of children’s book illustrations clickable?

Tags: javascript, css, image

I have a design from a client who is a children’s book illustrator. The site will be done in WordPress so they can edit certain pages etc. On some pages there will be illustrations that will also have clickable areas.

I suggest using Flash to show the illustrations, but they don’t like Flash at all.

I was thinking the other option was to use CSS background images with `<div>`s to position as clickable, but this is cumbersome.

Slicing the images into bits and pieces is also cumbersome due the the organic nature of the shapes and illustrations.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML image maps?](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp)

Comment: My main worry with image maps etc, is the browser support? ie. How much tweaking will I have to do for ie vs firefox etc

Comment: @Driftwood: in my experience, no tweaking is required. Image maps have been around for ages.

Comment: @Driftwood: if the images are too intricate for image slicing, then I think image maps are your only option: they’re the only widely-supported HTML/CSS feature that allows for defining non-oblong shapes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an image map. They will allow you to define an area of an image and assign an onclick event or href.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp

Comment: My main worry with image maps etc, is the browser support? ie. How much tweaking will I have to do for ie vs firefox etc